# add a list of vectors to get sum vector from tibble

Tags: r

I have a tibble ready, it looks like this

```
# A tibble: 156 x 2
   index new_r      
   <int> <list>     
 1     3 <dbl [158]>
 2     4 <dbl [158]>
 3     5 <dbl [158]>
 4     6 <dbl [158]>
 5     7 <dbl [158]>
 6     8 <dbl [158]>
 7     9 <dbl [158]>
 8    10 <dbl [158]>
 9    11 <dbl [158]>
10    12 <dbl [158]>
# ... with 146 more rows
```

I want to get a new vector `<dbl [158]>` which is the sum of all the vectors in the column `new_r`

What is the best/easiest way?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide some sample data through `dput`.

Comment: `result = Reduce("+", your_data$new_r)`